# Can antenna VSWR be corrected?

Tags: antenna, impedance-matching, tuner

For [this antenna](http://www.terk.com/radio-antennas/?sku=ADVANTAGE), which cites a VSWR of 1.4, can that be improved (decreased) with the use of a matching network? Could the matching network be between the feed cable and the board or must it be between the antenna and the feed cable?

Comment: On the AM band, for a receiver ... you're over-thinking it. Just connect it. It's not like you'll have 30kW of power reflected back into a transmitter. Not a reliably measurable signal loss, no.

Comment: Ok. This won't cause signal loss?

Comment: With all due respect: If antenna design questions are considered "off-topic" in an ELECTRICAL ENGINEERING forum, I daresay that James Clerk Maxwell would be very disappointed in you. Amazing

Comment: In an effort to shed some light on your question, I would say this, "Yes, it can be improved with a matching network, but at a 1.4 VSWR, it hardly seems worth the effort, and your EIRP could be lower even with a lower/better VSWR."

Comment: Hmm. This seems like a legit question, which would lead to better understanding of RF fundamentals. Vote to reopen, anyone?

Comment: Not addressing should you or shouldn't you do it.  A matching network can be inserted in the antenna path to lower the VSWR.  It can be inserted between the transmission line and receiver, or between the antenna and transmission line.  There are circumstances that influence where it's placed.  Understand that the matching network will exhibit its own set of losses as does the transmission line.  Also, depending on the matching method, it could be broadband or be selective which requires retuning; both have their merits.

Comment: @bitsmack I agree it's a perfectly reasonable question (reopened) even though the answer is basically "don't bother". If you're after the last 0.5dB of performance then it's theoretically possible ... but you'd be better starting off with a decent AM loop antenna instead. Perhaps https://aa7ee.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/a-tuned-loop-antenna-for-the-am-broadcast-band/  or https://www.radiomagonline.com/misc/shielded-loop-antennas-for-the-am-band Much more likely potential for improved performance.